# I had an issue in Stack area chart in d3 charts while I am handling negative values that I had an white space between the graph

Tags: d3.js

I need a Stack area chart with negative values and positive values using d3 charts using json data

I need a perfect stack area chart
[This is the image that consist of white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuSwm.png)

I need a image without white space in it, It is because I had been used StackOffset diverging, Is there any other method in it

Comment: Hello Merlins, I think that what you are trying to achieve is impossible. You can't stack area with positive and negative values, for example if your first area has only positive value and your second area has only negative value, how are you supposed to stack them? The second area should “decrease” the first area?